# How is a Scoped service instance handled in a .NET Core Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-core

I copied this from `ConfigureServices` in a web application I'm building, where I'm trying to move away from the web and only use a console app or service:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDbConnection, SqlConnection>(c => new SqlConnection(App.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The console app works fine, but I'm wondering how the lifetime of the connection is handled. If and when is the connection closed and or disposed? Or does this behave the same as a transient instance, and I should dispose it myself?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653561/how-would-addscoped-behave-outside-asp-net-core

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you build `IServiceProvider` from `IServiceCollection` (`BuildServiceProvider` method) and you use this instance of `IServiceProvider` to resolve `IDbConnection` you will get same instance of `IDbConnection` every time. Scope is connected to `IServiceProvider`. to create new scope you need to resolve from the container `IServiceScopeFactory` and use it to create `IServiceProvider` that is scoped:

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
   var scopedConnection = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnection>();      
}
```

Connection will be disposed when scope is disposed.

In ASP Core scopes are managed for you by middleware which creates new scope and then uses `IServiceProvider` attached to this scope to resolve Controller and everything within this web request. In console application you need to manage scopes yourself.

Comment: how is a scopeFactory connected with a service collection?

Comment: `IServiceScopeFactory` is automatically registered in `IServiceCollection` by the framework so you don't need to register it manually. Later on you can simply resolve it from `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Is it expensive to create scopes? I'm in a situation where my code (GraphQL resolvers) needs to existing in a singleton outer scope, but I need to get a scoped instance of something to reference the HTTP request. The only way I see to do that is to create my own scope and resolve within that, hoping that's not an expensive op.

Comment: If you need to access `HttpContext` in singleton you can use `IHttpContextAccessor`. Regarding cost of creating scope then I would say that you need to benchmark this but since ASP is creating new scope for each request it can't be to expensive.

Comment: Does it mean that `AddScoped` dependencies for a console application silently turn into singletons and that's why they work "automagically" without you having to create an explicit scope?

Comment: @JustAMartin Yes, pretty much; more of a `Singleton lifetime`. Scoped lifetime in asp.net is a request, in a console app it is the lifetime of the app unless otherwise configured.