# How would AddScoped() behave outside Asp.net core?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Let's say I want to use dependency injection in a console application that would run as an Azure web job. Doing so I am reusing my custom service registration method called "AddATonOfServices()" which I use on a related Asp.net application.

My question is, how would the services that are registered in "AddATonOfServices()" using AddScoped() behave now in the console App? are they behaving like Transient or Singleton, or HOW? Would there be any unexpected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will be resolved as scoped, if you create a scope via `IServiceScopeFactory`.

```
// provider is the root container
using(var scope = provider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedService>();
    // do something
}
// scope will be disposed and all scoped and transient services which implement IDisposable
```

If you resolve a **scoped** service from the root container, then it will be effectively a singleton (assuming `provider` lives as long as the application does)

Comment: So, if I even resolve from the root container a service that was registered as a Transient it will be a singleton? do you mean that regardless of how it was registered when you retrieve it it will be singleton?

Comment: No, transient is always transient. But scoped services become effective singletons, when resolved from root container

Comment: "If you resolve a scoped service from the root container, then it will be effectively a singleton" This depends on how you build the service provider. There is a `BuildServiceProvider` overload that allows preventing resolving Scoped instances from the root container. This overload was added after the 1.0 release. Calling `BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)` however is still a half-baked solution, because you can still inject transients into singletons, without the service provider complaining.