# Why does a console application with IHostedService work with scoped dependencies when there is no explicit scope?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, console-application, .net-6.0

I was creating a console application that is reusing a library with some dependencies registered as `AddScoped`. I was afraid my app would fail if I won't create a scope myself, since I have already seen some Stack Overflow questions regarding scope management in console applications.

However, I was surprised to see that my app worked just fine!

Now I'm puzzled as to how does it work and which component is resolving the scoped dependencies automagically for me? Is `CreateDefaultBuilder` doing something special? Or is it `RunConsoleAsync`?

I have created a simple console application as a proof of concept (the code is for .net6 style of Program.cs). You might expect DI to complain about being unable to resolve `IMyInterface` dependency because I have registered it with `AddScoped` and `MyImplementation2` depends on it (and, in turn, the final host depends on `IMyInterface2` singleton) and I am not creating a scope anywhere.

At least, in a web app it would fail screaming at me that the singleton `MyImplementation2` was unable to resolve a scoped implementation of `IMyInterface`.

However, the console app succeeds and prints out the text from both `Hello()` methods.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface2, MyImplementation2>()
                .AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>()
            .AddHostedService<MyConsoleHostedService>();
    }).RunConsoleAsync();

internal interface IMyInterface
{
    void Hello();
}

internal class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, MyImplementation");
    }
}

internal interface IMyInterface2
{
    void Hello();
}

internal class MyImplementation2 : IMyInterface2
{
    IMyInterface myScoped;

    public MyImplementation2(IMyInterface my)
    {
        myScoped = my;
    }

    public void Hello()
    {
        myScoped.Hello();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, MyImplementation2");
    }
}

internal sealed class MyConsoleHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime;
    private readonly IMyInterface2 myDependency;

    public MyConsoleHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime,
        IMyInterface2 myDependency)
    {   
        this.appLifetime = appLifetime;
        this.myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                myDependency.Hello();
                appLifetime.StopApplication();
            });
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So, why does it work? Where is the scope and how is the scoped `IMyInterface` resolved for the singleton `MyImplementation2`?

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865505/3390788) might point to what you're looking for  insofar as an answer goes.  Your service is being resolved from the root scope if I'm understanding that correctly.